# 2 foreign keys referencing same primary key laraavel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-controller, laravel-models

I'm relatively new in Laravel and I would like to learn how to create recursive relation with 2 foreign keys referencing the primary key.

I have table `item_associations` which has 2 FK referenced to the `item table`'s PK:

```
Schema::create('item_associations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->unsignedInteger('item_id');
        $table->foreign('item_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('items');
        $table->unsignedInteger('item2_id');
        $table->foreign('item2_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('items');
    });
```

Here is my `ItemAssociation model`:

```
protected $table = 'item_associations';

    public function items(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Item','item_id');
    }

    public function item2_id(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Item','item2_id', 'item_id');
    }
```

here is my `Item model`:

```
protected $table = 'items';

public function item_associations(){
        return $this->hasMany(UserType::class);
    }
```

here is my Welcome controller:

```
$item_association = DB::table('item_associations')
        ->join ('items', 'item_associations.item_id', '=', 'items.id')
        ->join ('items', 'item_associations.item2_id', '=', 'items.id')
        ->get();
return view('welcome', [
            'item_association' => $item_association,    
            ]);
```

Apparently, I receive an error:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'items' (SQL: select * from `item_associations` inner join `items` on `item_associations`.`item_id` = `items`.`id` inner join `items` on `item_associations`.`item2_id` = `items`.`id`)

in blade I would like to get something like this:
[image]

Comment: Is there any reason for not using many-to-many relationship?

Comment: If item2_id is equal to item_id then it should not have a separate relationship. If they are different ids then you need to use a many to many relationship.

Comment: @Bulent i want my item2_id be related with item_id, for instance, if the customer orders food that is item_it there will be additional items(let says gravies) that may come with the chosen item that's why I need item2_id

Comment: @DiegoDieh i want my item2_id be related with item_id, for instance, if the customer orders food that is item_it there will be additional items(let says gravies) that may come with the chosen item that's why I need item2_id

Answer (score 1):

What if you want to add another thing besides gravies?

I can suggest you 2 options.

First, instead of creating foreign keys in the separate columns, keep ids in a column by casting them an array. This is easy to setup and very flexible way.

Second, which is a better way in my opinion, using proper eloquent relationships like following:

The structure you want to achieve is a form of many-to-many relationship.

You need 3 tables: items, associations, association_item.

```php
// Models/Item.php

public function associations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Association::class);
}

// Models\Association.php

public function items()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class);
}

public function additions()
{
    return $this->hasMany($this, 'parent_id', 'id');
}

// Migrations

Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    // some fields
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('associations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    // some fields
    $table->foreingId('parent_id')->nullable()->costrained('assosiations')
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('association_item', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->foreignId('item_id');
    $table->foreingId('association_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```